# How to find position of transparent part in UIImage..?

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

I am developing App and want to know about how to find position of transparent part of `UIImage`.

Comment: I'd say that you need to "scan" all the pixels?  Does your image have only ONE and Squared transparent part?

Comment: no transparent part not only square but only one part in particular image..